# what type to give props if they are HTMLElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this **Layout** component in React with typescript template:

```
import React from "react";

const Layout = (body: React.ReactNode) => {
return (
    <div>
        {/* Here will be Header */}
        {body}
    </div>
);
}

export default Layout;
```

and component **Home**:

```
import './style.css'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';

const Home = () => {
return (
    <Layout>
        <section>
            {/* Some data */}
        </section>
    </Layout>
)
}

export default Home;
```

Typescript swears at the wrong type, so I can't choose the type of **body**.
I'm just starting to learn typescript(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of a React function component is an object of properties typically called "props".

The `children` prop is what is what JSX child nodes are passed as therefore you can access them via your prop object as such:

```
const Layout = ({ children: body }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        {/* Here will be Header */}
        {body}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `children` instead:

```js
import React from "react";

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: You are welcome. Keep the name `children` rather than body since every other devs will understand immediatly what it is.

Comment: Please, consider marking you question as answered to help other users. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `body` should be `children`
2. Props are passed in an object so you have to wrap arguments with `{}`

```
import React from "react";

const Layout = ({ children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Here will be Header */}
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: you forgot to destructure children ;)